# How to automate [through ARM / PowerShell] Azure CDN from Verizon Premium rule engine to override HTTP behavior

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-cdn

We have a requirement to override HTTP behavior of Azure CDN, found that "[Azure CDN Premium from Verizon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine)" is available to override the behavior. We want to automate the HTTP behavior in ARM template while creating/configuring CDN during CI/CD. Going through the ARM template but did not found the "[CDN Premium from Verizon options"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-cdn-with-ruleseengine-cacheoverride).

Now we can Implement security headers in [Standard edition](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-content-delivery-network-standard-rules-engine-is-now-available/), but did found ARM template to implement security headers in standard edition.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-content-delivery-network-standard-rules-engine-is-now-available/

Thanks and please let me know if any other option available to override HTTP behavior without manual intervention.

Deb

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try creating endpoint and manage the delivery rules using Azure cli. Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#commands) for more information.

[Here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42603) is a similar issue asking for ARM template examples. You track this issue or submit an new issue for your own.

Comment: Thanks Levi, will try Azure CLI

Comment: Now we can implement few Security headers in Standard Edition, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-content-delivery-network-standard-rules-engine-is-now-available/ Can I get some ARM template for Standard Edition